# Could not resolve 'deb.debian.org' while apt update debian 11 bullseye

Tags: debian, apt, software-updates

I installed debian 11 Bullseye and here is my source.list file:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye main contrib non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security main contrib non-free

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates main contrib non-free

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-backports main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-backports main contrib non-free
```

While I try to update with `apt update`, here are the errors I get:

```
Err:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease
Could not resolve 'deb.debian.org'
Err:2 http://security.debian.org.debian-security bullseye InRelease
Could not resolve 'deb.debian.org'
Err:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates InRelease
Could not resolve 'deb.debian.org'
Err:4 http://security.debian.org.debian bullseye-backports InRelease
Could not resolve 'deb.debian.org'
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/bullseye/InRelease Could not resolve 'deb.debian.org'
W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/debian-security/dists/bullseye-security/InRelease Could not resolve 'security.debian.org'
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/bullseye-updates/InRelease Could not resolve 'deb.debian.org'
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/bullseye-backports/InRelease Could not resolve 'deb.debian.org'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

What is wrong with my source.list file? Is there anything else to set up?

Comment: Welcome, the urls are accessible, at least for me. Are you behind a proxy/firewall?

Comment: DNS is not setup correctly and/or blocked by firewall.

Comment: do any domains resolve?

Answer (score 9):

As root, make a copy of `/etc/resolv.conf` (CLI `cp /etc/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf.orig`). Then run the following commands.

```
# printf '%s\n' 'nameserver 1.1.1.1' 'nameserver 1.0.0.1' > /etc/resolv.conf
# ping -c 4 deb.debian.org; printf 'Return code: %s\n' "$?"
```

If last line is `Return code:  0`, `apt update` should work fine.