# Error code 2 from 'deb.debian.org' in apt update while GUI broken after Debian 12 extremely slow after upgrade from 11 to 12

Tags: debian, gnome, troubleshooting

I upgraded my Debian 11 to 12, after which Debian became extremely slow.
I started to remove packages, but got GUI broken after running this (I did by accident Home Assistant installation on my Debian 12 by guide [Installing Home Assistant Supervised using Debian 12](https://community.home-assistant.io/t/installing-home-assistant-supervised-using-debian-12/200253) until to the command `apt install apparmor jq wget curl udisks2 libglib2.0-bin network-manager dbus lsb-release systemd-journal-remote systemd-resolved -y`, although I was planning to do it on my RP4). But still, I do not think this made my Debian slow, because it was extremely slow also after the fresh installation.

Command that I run which broke GUI, now only starting in commandline:

```
apt purge apparmor jq wget curl udisks2 libglib2.0-bin network-manager dbus lsb-release systemd-journal-remote systemd-resolved
```

I get the message when trying to get packages back in `apt update`:

```
Could not resolve 'deb.debian.org'
```

I was reading this thread [Could not resolve 'deb.debian.org' while apt update debian 11 bullseye](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/680334/could-not-resolve-deb-debian-org-while-apt-update-debian-11-bullseye), where the command:

```
# printf '%s\n' 'nameserver 1.1.1.1' 'nameserver 1.0.0.1' > /etc/resolv.conf
# ping -c 4 deb.debian.org; printf 'Return code: %s\n' "$?"
```

Gives me the error code

```
Return code: 2
```

Still my GUI is broken, I did with `tasksel` desktop gnome install, but still only in commandline and starting Gnome not working.

How to get the deb.debian.org work and gnome back working?

OS: Debian 12
Computer: Asus TUF Dash F15

Comment: Try to install the deb package `systemd-resolved`. It it doesn't work try to configure your network from the CLI. Then try to install the missing package.

Comment: I get the same error ´Could not resolve 'deb.debian.org'´ from ´sudo apt install systemd-resolved´. How to config network?

Comment: `ip` and `iproute` for manual config https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Network_configuration

Comment: How to do it with 'ip'?

Comment: What does the /etc/resolv.conf contain? 

Do you have an /etc/nsswitch.conf file ?